# What are side effects of Suspension?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

After the suspension of my account from Super User, I noticed that my reputation was gone.

What are the side-effects of being 'boxed' or suspended?

Comment: Thanks George - I think you kept all the key points ;-p

Comment: "NOTE : IF YOU ARE EDITTING THIS QUESTION DONT REMOVE MY FEELINGS " -- tl;dr version: no fair, I want my rep back!

Comment: "this bad than adolf hitler" oh come on, that's *begging* to get meme'd

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hi Joe. After the suspension period (typically one week) your rep will be recalculated. So you're only temporarily at 1 rep. For more info, see [*A day in the penalty box*](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

I must say that playing a [Godwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godwin%27s_law) right there in your question is not such a good idea. You may want to remove that remark and relax a bit. It's not the end of the word. (Oh, and may I suggest a spelling and grammar checker?)

Consider emailing `team@superuser.com` if you want personal feedback on your penalty.

Comment: i was very sad before your answer . now i am so happy :-)

Comment: @joe: good to hear that, but perhaps you shouldn't feel *too* good about the situation. It should feel a bit like punishment after all :)

Comment: stephan, this is not a Godwin case, look at joe's prev question.

Comment: @Henk: I missed that one, I see. "Interesting" question. For future reference, the link is http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27063/would-adolf-hitler-be-considered-an-offensive-gravatar

Answer (score 3):

Call me slow, but none of your linked accounts are currently suspended... do you have others?

Anyway; suspension:

- prevents posting, editing, etc
- prevents commenting (although it didn't once)
- prevents you gaining rep for the duration
- causes a recalc when the suspension ends

Comment: The suspension must have been lifted in the past fifteen minutes... when I looked he was indeed at 1 rep.

Comment: i have completed my suspension now today only ;)